# Perl Workflow module with validator

Tags: perl, workflow, validation

i'm trying to get things work with perl Workflow module - http://search.cpan.org/~jonasbn/Workflow/

I managed to figure out how it works with workflows, actions, conditions and all but i can't get it to apply validator class to the action.

My _init method from validator loads and prints out the line that i put there for testing but validate method is not triggered ever. Also, when dumping $self->get_validators() from action class i get empty list.

I created a short example so please try it and help out if you see the problem. Tnx!

link to code - https://github.com/vmcooper/perl_workflow_test

**Running the program**

Program starts with

```
Answer: London
If you answer right the action should change state to 'finished'. Try answering wrong first.
Capital city of England:
```

if you answer "Birmingham" it should write

```
Your answer is being validated!
```

and ask the question again.

When you answer "London" it should

```
Correct! Current state of workflow is - finished
```

**edit** Now it writes out "Correct! Current state of workflow is - finished" whatever your answer is.

workflow_test.pl

```perl
use strict;
use Log::Log4perl     qw( get_logger );
use Workflow::Factory qw( FACTORY );

Log::Log4perl::init( 'log4perl.conf' );
system('clear');

# Stock the factory with the configurations; we can add more later if we want
FACTORY->add_config_from_file(
    workflow   => 'workflow.xml',
    action     => 'action.xml',
    persister  => 'persister.xml',
    validator  => 'validator.xml'
    );

my $workflow = FACTORY->create_workflow( "Workflow1" );
my $context = $workflow->context;

while ( $workflow->state eq "INITIAL" ) {
    print "If you answer right the action should change state to 'finished'. Try answering wrong first.\n";
    my $city = get_response( "Capital city of England: " );
    print "You answered - $city\n";
    $workflow->execute_action( 'action1' );

    if( $workflow->state eq "INITIAL" ) {
        print "Your answer is wrong! try again!\n\n";
    }
}

print "\nCorrect! Current state of workflow is - ".$workflow->state."\n\n";


# Generic routine to read a response from the command-line (defaults,
# etc.) Note that return value has whitespace at the end/beginning of
# the routine trimmed.

sub get_response {
    my ( $msg ) = @_;
    print $msg;
    my $response = <STDIN>;
    chomp $response;
    $response =~ s/^\s+//;
    $response =~ s/\s+$//;
    return $response;
}
```

workflow.xml

```xml
<workflow>
     <type>Workflow1</type>
     <time_zone>local</time_zone>
     <description>This is my workflow.</description>
     <persister>Persister1</persister>

     <state name="INITIAL">
        <action name="action1" resulting_state="finished"/>
     </state>

    <state name="finished" />
 </workflow>
```

action.xml

```xml
<actions>
    <action name="action1" class="App::Action::Action1" >
        <validator name="validator1">
            <arg>$city</arg>
        </validator>
    </action>
</actions>
```

validator.xml

```xml
<validators>
    <validator name="validator1" class="App::Validator::Validator1">
        <param name="answer" value="London" />
    </validator>
</validators>
```

App::Action::Action1.pm

```perl
package App::Action::Action1;

use strict;
use base qw( Workflow::Action );
use Workflow::Exception qw( validation_error configuration_error );
use Data::Dumper;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    my $self = {};
    bless ($self, $class);

    return $self;
}

sub execute {
    my $self = shift;
    my $wf = shift;
    print "App::Action::Action1::Execute\n";
    print "Validators: ".Dumper($self->get_validators())."\n";
}

1;
```

App::Validator::Validator1.pm

```perl
package App::Validator::Validator1;

use strict;
use base qw( Workflow::Validator );
use Workflow::Exception qw( validation_error configuration_error );
use Data::Dumper;
use Carp qw(carp);

sub _init {
    my ( $self, $params ) = @_;
     unless ( $params->{answer} ) {
         configuration_error
             "You must define a value for 'answer' in ",
             "declaration of validator ", $self->name;
     }
     if ( ref $params->{answer} ) {
         configuration_error
             "The value for 'answer' must be a simple scalar in ",
             "declaration of validator ", $self->name;
     }
     print "Answer: ".$params->{answer}."\n";
     $self->{ answer => $params->{answer} };
}

sub validate {
    my ( $self, $wf, $city ) = @_;

    print "Your answer is being validated!\n";
    print "Your answer is - ".$city."\n";

    my $check;

    if ( $city eq $self->{answer} ){
        $check = 1;
    } else {
        $check = 0;
    }
    unless ( $check ) {
        validation_error "Validation error!";
    }
}

1;
```

Edit:
If i dump workflow object right after creation and before any action is executed i get this:

```json
Workflow: $VAR1 = bless( {
    '_states' => {
        'INITIAL' => bless( {
            ...,
            '_actions' => {
                'action1' => {
                    'resulting_state' => 'finished',
                    'name' => 'action1'
                }
            },
            '_factory' => bless( {
                ...,
                '_action_config' => {
                    'default' => {
                        'action1' => {
                            'name' => 'action1',
                            'class' => 'App::Action::Action1',
                            'validator' => [
                                {
                                    'arg' => [
                                         '$city'
                                       ],
                                    'name' => 'validator1'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                '_validators' => {
                    'validator1' => bless( {
                        'name' => 'validator1',
                        'class' => 'App::Validator::Validator1',
                        'PARAMS' => {}
                    }, 'App::Validator::Validator1' )
                },
                '_validator_config' => {
                    'validator1' => {
                        'answer' => 'London',
                        'name' => 'validator1',
                        'class' => 'App::Validator::Validator1'
                    }
                },
                ...
            }, 'Workflow::Factory' ),
            'type' => 'Workflow1',
            'PARAMS' => {}
        }, 'Workflow::State' ),
        'finished' => $VAR1->{'_states'}{'INITIAL'}{'_factory'}{'_workflow_state'}{'Workflow1'}[1]
    },
    ...
}, 'Workflow' );
```

As you can see, validator is here and everything is set up and looks like it's ok but the validator is not applied.

Comment: hm...i can sum it up to be clearer and minimal as this:

Validator is not applied before action is executed.

Simple as that. I also included the code and a github repo so i really don't know how to be more precise.

Comment: The code is simple as it can be because i'm just hoping to understand how this module works. You can see what it should do, under "Running the program". It's bolded. Let me give you a notice that i'm using perl module here which i didn't wrote myself. There is a link on the top to the cpan where you can see the module i'm talking about. That is why i'm asking if somebody knows how to use it and what did i do wrong in config files or classes?

Comment: Sorry, missed the addition of the Birmingham example. The question is indeed complete now, thanks.

Comment: I just printed out a few dumps from the Workflow.pm itself.
 I put the dump in the "execute_action" method right before "$action->validate($self);" and i tried to dump "$action->get_validators()". The result was empty! So this is why validator never gets executed. Problem is that he is in the workflow object as you can see in my question but it is not applied to the action. Did i miss something in the configuration or this is a bug in the Workflow module?

Comment: You example is not complete, you refer to persister.xml, which is not included, could you add that?

jonasbn

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we will have to wait for this a bit or we can participate in a project to get this functionaity done.

Scroll to the "get_validators" heading and you will se a "#TODO" mark.
I'm not sure whether this means the documentation needs to be done or code but i did look at the code a bit and it looks like the code needs to be done for this functionality.
http://search.cpan.org/~jonasbn/Workflow-1.41/lib/Workflow/Factory.pm

Correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I located several issues in your example.

Action1.pm has a constructor, this interferes with the inheritance, So this should be deleted leaving your action class as follows

```
package App::Action::Action1;

use strict;
use base qw( Workflow::Action );
use Workflow::Exception qw( validation_error configuration_error );
use Data::Dumper;

sub execute {
    my $self = shift;
    my $wf = shift;
    print "App::Action::Action1::Execute\n";
    print "Validators: ".Dumper($self->get_validators())."\n";
}

1;
```

The main issue that your application receives the input from the user, but you never feed it to the workflow. This has be done using context, like so:

```
$context->param( answer => $city );
```

The validator should looks as follows:

```
package App::Validator::Validator1;

use strict;
use base qw( Workflow::Validator );
use Workflow::Exception qw( validation_error configuration_error );
use Data::Dumper;
use Carp qw(carp);

sub _init {
    my ( $self, $params ) = @_;
     unless ( $params->{answer} ) {
         configuration_error
             "You must define a value for 'answer' in ",
             "declaration of validator ", $self->name;
     }
     if ( ref $params->{answer} ) {
         configuration_error
             "The value for 'answer' must be a simple scalar in ",
             "declaration of validator ", $self->name;
     }
     print "Answer: ".$params->{answer}."\n";
     $self->{answer} = $params->{answer};
}

sub validate {
    my ( $self, $wf ) = @_;

    my $city = $wf->context->param('answer');

    print "Your answer is being validated!\n";
    print "Your answer is - ".$city."\n";

    my $check;

    if ( $city eq $self->{answer} ){
        $check = 1;
    } else {
        $check = 0;
    }
    unless ( $check ) {
        validation_error "Validation error!";
    }
}

1;
```

And your main application should resemble the following:

```
use strict;
use Log::Log4perl     qw( get_logger );
use Workflow::Factory qw( FACTORY );
use lib qw(lib);

Log::Log4perl::init( 'log4perl.conf' );
system('clear');

# Stock the factory with the configurations; we can add more later if we want
FACTORY->add_config_from_file(
    workflow   => 'workflow.xml',
    action     => 'action.xml',
    persister  => 'persister.xml',
    validator  => 'validator.xml'
    );

my $workflow = FACTORY->create_workflow( "Workflow1" );
my $context = $workflow->context;

while ( $workflow->state eq "INITIAL" ) {
    print "If you answer right the action should change state to 'finished'. Try answering wrong first.\n";
    my $city = get_response( "Capital city of England: " );
    print "You answered - $city\n";
    $context->param( answer => $city );
    $workflow->execute_action( 'action1' );

    if( $workflow->state eq "INITIAL" ) {
        print "Your answer is wrong! try again!\n\n";
    }
}

print "\nCorrect! Current state of workflow is - ".$workflow->state."\n\n";


# Generic routine to read a response from the command-line (defaults,
# etc.) Note that return value has whitespace at the end/beginning of
# the routine trimmed.

sub get_response {
    my ( $msg ) = @_;
    print $msg;
    my $response = <STDIN>;
    chomp $response;
    $response =~ s/^\s+//;
    $response =~ s/\s+$//;
    return $response;
}
```

I understand your confusion, since the documentation does not properly reflect this fact and it cannot be read from the example application in the distribution. I will update the documentation accordingly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18067782)

Comment: I have created [a PR](https://github.com/vmcooper/perl_workflow_test/pull/1) for your Github repository with all the files, I am sorry I overlooked this before creating my own and the files that was missing in your question was of course available in the repository. My own response lacks the changes made to the validator, I will updated it.

Comment: @guillaume-darmont would it be possible for you to review my answer again, I have updated it - and I would like to get the -1 addressed, if the answer of course justifies this - thanks

Comment: I cannot do anything about the -1, since I was only asked by SO to do some review on your original post (https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47498915/1). The downvote is not mine.