# Perl Workflow manual action termination

Tags: perl, workflow, validation

Since i'm not able to solve the problem via validators
[Perl Workflow module with validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921691/perl-workflow-module-with-validator),
i'm thinking of creating methods in action classes and call them when i need them.
Aproaching this way i will need a way of terminating the Action execution by returning "false" to the Workflow.
This way the workflow knows that it should not progress to the next state.

How can i manually terminate Action execution in perl Workflow?

Thank you

Comment: I would appreciate a comment after -1 but...there are all kinds of people out there!
If i'm not clear in my question i will happily answer on anything that is unclear here.

Comment: I think it's a good question, but it would help if you fixed interpunction and spelling.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited my question a bit, making a sentences shorter.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a *hack* since Workflow is a state machine. You could look into [Workflow::State](https://metacpan.org/pod/Workflow::State) for actions with several resulting states, as mentioned in the documentation for [Workflow::Action execute](https://metacpan.org/pod/Workflow::Action#execute(-$workflow-)).